# Two algorithm counters for different types of algorithms

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I want to create two separate algorithm counters in Latex. The first one is for my main algorithms, the second one for subroutines.

In particular, I now have the following algorithms (in order):

Algorithm 1

Algorithm 2

Algorithm 3

This I want to change into (in order):

Algorithm 1

Subroutine 1 (so different name and different counter)

Algorithm 2

How can this be done?

I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}    
\usepackage{algorithmic}     
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{NameForAlgo1}
\label{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{NameForSubRoutine1}
\label{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{NameForAlgo2}
\label{}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What package do you use for formatting your algorithms? There are many options out there, each of which require different approach to a solution.

Comment: I use the following to create my algorithms:

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Name}
    \label{}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

Comment: So is it [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (which provides `algorithmic`) or [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)'s `algorithmic`? Please, before you answer in comment, consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to your post via an edit. Click on the MWE link and read the post...

Comment: I hope this MWE is sufficient to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`algorithms` is based on the package `float`, so one really simple fix would be to just declare a new float for subroutines in the preamble. To make sure they show up in the List of Algorithms you should probably make sure they go to file with a `loa` extension. You should also probably make sure you have a ToC sectioning command for subroutines, since I don't think those are automatically created when `\newfloat` is used.

But if you add

`\newfloat{subroutine}{htbp}{loa}
\floatname{subroutine}{Subroutine}
\makeatletter\newcommand\l@subroutine{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}\makeatother`

Before you begin the document, [edit: and then use `\begin{subroutine}\end{subroutine}` in place of `\begin{algorithm}` where needed, ] and  I think you should be fine.